# How do I create a URL with an array query parameter in Play Framework using Scala?

Tags: arrays, playframework, query-string

In Play Framework using Scala, I want to accept the following URL with an array query parameter:

```
path?ids=1&ids=2
```

What do I put in the route and controller to accept the above URL?

`conf/routes`

```
GET    /path    MyController.path(ids: ???)
```

`MyController.scala`

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
  def path(ids: ???) = ??? // implement
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`conf/routes`

```
GET    /path    MyController.path(ids: Seq[Long] ?= Seq.empty)
```

`MyController.scala`

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
  def path(ids: Seq[Long]) = ??? // implement
}
```

Note that `?=` makes `ids` optional in the URL.